# Почему код работает не корректно. При введении Лампочка/лампочка, цикл не останавливается

Tags: python, циклы

```
print("Висит груша, нельзя скушать. Что это такое?") 
s = "" 
while s != "Лампочка" or s != "лампочка": 
    s = input("Введите ответ и нажмите Enter: ") 
print("Вы отгадали загадку!")
```

Comment: потому что ``s`` ВСЕГДА будет или не равно "Лампочка" (если ты ввел "лампочка") или не равно "лампочка" (если ты ввел "Лампочка"). Изменяй условие.

Comment: Я как амбассадор [законов де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), сообщаю, что тут стоит вынести отрицание за скобки, а при выносе отрицания `or` меняется на `and` и наоборот, в итоге условие превращается в `not (s == "Лампочка" and s == "лампочка")`, условие в скобках всегда ложное (т.к. переменная не может одновременно быть равна двум значениям), добавляем not - получается всегда True, цикл становится бесконечным.

Comment: А если ввод будет `ЛАМПОЧКА`? Здесь дело в регистронезависимом сравнении. `while s.lower() != "лампочка":`

Comment: @АлексейР Нет, здесь дело именно в неправильном условии. А регистронезависимое сравнение, конечно, решит проблему, но не объяснит, почему сейчас не работает.

Comment: @Эникейщик с одной стороны согласен, с другой нет. Вопрос звучит довольно широко - "почему код работает некорректно?". Ответ, конечно, такой - потому что условие задано неправильно. Но зацикливаться на булевой алгебре тоже не вариант, ибо это не решает проблему в общем смысле. Да, слова "Лампочка" и "лампочка" будут проходить, а "ЛАМПОЧКА" и "ЛаМпОчКа" и еще множество написаний - не будут. Поэтому разумно поменять подход к написанию условия.

Comment: @АлексейР  в этом случае задачу можно решить через lower(), но автор так и не узнает, почему его решение не работает. В другом случае решить задачу через lower() будет нельзя, а автор столкнется этой же самой проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код работает:

```py
print("Висит груша, нельзя скушать. Что это такое?")

while True:  # (1)
    s = input("Введите ответ и нажмите Enter: ")  # (2)

    if s in ("Лампочка", "лампочка"):  # (3)
        print("Вы отгадали загадку!")  # (4)
        break  # (5)
```

1. Запускаем бесконечный цикл.
2. Запрашиваем ответ
3. Проверяем верен ли он
4. Если ответ верен, выводим нужное сообщение и...
5. ...выходим.

Также если нужно распознавание ответа в любом регистре, то вот код:

```py
print("Висит груша, нельзя скушать. Что это такое?")

while True: 
    s = input("Введите ответ и нажмите Enter: ")

    if s.lower() == "лампочка":
        print("Вы отгадали загадку!")
        break
```

Comment: Как быть с ответом "ЛаМпОчКа"?

Comment: @АлексейР а в вопросе про ничего такое и не говорилось :)

Comment: @АлексейР но всё таки добавил ещё вариант.

Comment: К сведению: для корректного сравнения без учета регистра букв для любых языков есть специальный метод [casefold](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold)

Comment: я поставил минус, потому что ответ не отвечает на вопрос, почему код автора не работает, и не позволит в будущем такой ошибки не допускать. Да, код в ответе делает то, что хотелось бы автору вопроса. Но вопрос был "почему код не работает", а не "как сделать по-другому"

Comment: Раз уж пошел холивар, то, по моему мнению, гораздо конструктивнее написать свой *более лучший* вариант ответа, нежели минусовать чужой

Comment: Спасибо, что столько решений написали) Мне просто не понятно почему цикл while не завершается, ведь условие ИЛИ ТО, ИЛИ ТО срабатывает, и должно вывести из цикла

Answer (score 0):

> Мне просто не понятно почему цикл `while` не завершается, ведь условие
> **ИЛИ ТО, ИЛИ ТО** срабатывает, и должно вывести из цикла

В том то и дело, что в `while` пишется **условие продолжения работы цикла**. И условие `s != x or s != y` **всегда будет истинным** (в случае, если `x` не одинаковое с `y`), потому что `s` ведь не может быть одновременно равно двум разным вещам.

- если `s` будет равно `x`, то не выполнится условие `s != x`, но выполнится условие `s != y`
- если `s` будет равно `y`, то наоборот не сработает `s != y`, но сработает `s != x`
- а если `s` будет равно некоему `z` (не равному ни `x` ни `y`), то сработают сразу оба условия и цикл опять же продолжит работу

Из-за того, что у вас два условия (из которых хотя бы одно будет истинным, как я показал выше) объединены через `ИЛИ`, у вас суммарное условие всегда будет выполняться и цикл будет продолжать работать.

Так что ваше **условие продолжения работы цикла** явно должно быть написано через `И`, а не через `ИЛИ`.